# Knockout view model changes not propagating to DataTables UI when using pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, pagination, datatables

I am using a Knockout View Model and JQuery DataTables with pagination. There is an external process that can change the underlying values of the View Model. However, if the value is changed externally to 'false' and the specific item is not on the current page, the changes are not propagated to the UI. If the item is on the current page, it updates OK.

A **JSFiddle illustrating the problem can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pzmz8cuo/)**. If you go to the second page, and click the 'Change Item' (which changes the 11th item), the checkbox changes OK. However, if you re-run the JSFiddle and click the button while on the first page, it doesn't update the checkbox correctly on the second page.

The code I'm using to update the item:

```
 vm.itemsVM()[10].selected(false);
```

And the code to generate the table contents:

```
<!-- ko foreach: itemsVM -->
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data.selected" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I'm not sure why this isn't updating correctly and would really appreciate some help. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you'll need to include some extra code to get datatables playing nicely with knockout.  There's an [example here](http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/)

Comment: [See also this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622291/jquery-datatables-knockout-bootstrap-bug)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, James. However, using the suggested methods from datatables.net, it still isn't correctly invalidating and re-reading data for the row (this might be a separate issue). Here is the updated JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/0uhjypdj/

Comment: I guess 2nd page rows does not exists in DOM when you are on 1st page, that's why UI is not notified with changes when an underlying observable changes.